# User specific URL Redirection With Lighttpd

Tags: url, .htaccess, redirect, lighttpd

Apache web hosts have a user-configurable ~/.htaccess file that allows local redirects, for example, www.awesomesite.com => www.awesomesite.com/launchmyawesomeapp.cgi

In lighttpd I know there is a global /etc/lighttpd.conf file, but is there something local like the Apache htaccess file?

thanks,
joe

Answer (score 0):

You could use lighttpd's `include_shell` command to include a config from all user's `/home/` directory. You specify an executable (binary) optional with paramenter if you call an interpreter here. That program/script returns lighttpd-config formated text. To be able to restart lighttpd on config change you'd need a daemon or a cronjob for it (check for timestamp changes). This is, as far as I know, because lighttpd loads configs only on startup.